# When adding line segments in r, the facet_wrap order in ggplot is changed

Tags: r, ggplot2

I drew a boxplot in the following order:

```
Test <- data %>%  
  mutate(across(day, factor, levels=c("7 dpi","3 dpi","14 dpi", "21 dpi"))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = grp, y = lung, colour = grp)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA)+
  scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE, alpha=0.6)+
  geom_jitter(size=1.5)+
  facet_wrap(~day,nrow = 1,strip.position = "top")+
  labs(x="Groups", y = "Lung")+
  theme(legend.position="none",axis.text.x = element_text(colour="grey20",size=9,angle=0,hjust=.5,vjust=.5,face="plain"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(colour="grey20",size=9,angle=0,hjust=1,vjust=0,face="plain"),  
        axis.title.x = element_text(colour="black",size=10,angle=0,hjust=.5,vjust=0,face="bold"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(colour="black",size=10,angle=90,hjust=.5,vjust=.5,face="bold"),
        plot.title = element_text(size=18, face = "bold"))
```

[image]

But when I add a line to the chart, the order of the groups changes.I do not know what to do.

```
anno1.1 <- data.frame(
  day="3 dpi",
  x=c(1, 1, 2),
  xend=c(2, 1, 2),
  y=c(5, 5, 5),
  yend=c(5, 4.85, 4.85))

anno2.1 <- data.frame(
  day="7 dpi",
  x=c(2, 2, 6),
  xend=c(6, 2, 6),
  y=c(5, 5, 5),
  yend=c(5, 4.85, 4.85))
anno3.1 <- data.frame(
  day="14 dpi",
  x=c(2, 2, 6),
  xend=c(6, 2, 6),
  y=c(5, 5, 5),
  yend=c(5, 4.85, 4.85))

Test +
  geom_segment(data = anno1.1, aes(x = x,  y = y, xend=xend, yend=yend), inherit.aes = FALSE)+
  geom_segment(data = anno2.1, aes(x = x,  y = y, xend=xend, yend=yend), inherit.aes = FALSE)+
  geom_segment(data = anno3.1, aes(x = x,  y = y, xend=xend, yend=yend), inherit.aes = FALSE)+
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no reproducible data shared, so I can't test this solution, but I suggest combining your annotation data frames into a single data frame and specifying the level order as you do in your original data:

```
anno1.1 <- data.frame(
  day="3 dpi",
  x=c(1, 1, 2),
  xend=c(2, 1, 2),
  y=c(5, 5, 5),
  yend=c(5, 4.85, 4.85))

anno2.1 <- data.frame(
  day="7 dpi",
  x=c(2, 2, 6),
  xend=c(6, 2, 6),
  y=c(5, 5, 5),
  yend=c(5, 4.85, 4.85))
anno3.1 <- data.frame(
  day="14 dpi",
  x=c(2, 2, 6),
  xend=c(6, 2, 6),
  y=c(5, 5, 5),
  yend=c(5, 4.85, 4.85))

anno = rbind(anno1.1, anno2.1, anno3.1) %>%
  mutate(across(day, factor, levels=c("7 dpi","3 dpi","14 dpi", "21 dpi"))) 
  # note that the levels in your code do not match the plot -
  # probably a copy/paste typo. You probably want to change
  # both pieces of code to put 3 dpi before 7 dpi.
  # (the `across()` is pointless here, but I keep it for consistency)

# this has the advantage of simplifying your plotting code

Test +
  geom_segment(data = anno, aes(x = x,  y = y, xend=xend, yend=yend), inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  theme_classic()
```

Comment: Thanks your proposal.